# Проблема со вставкой массива в БД Python: int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Есть массив. Хочу его записать в БД. Получаю ошибку `'int' object is not iterable`

Пробовал поменять все колонки на `ar=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']` и получаю `Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 8, and there are 1 supplied.`

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема

```
sqlite_file = '/home/metr/python_proj/my_db.sqlite'

def insert(line_list):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
    c = conn.cursor()
    for item in line_list:
        c.executemany('insert into Goods values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', item)
    c.commit()

ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '6', 7, '8']
insert(ar)
```

Comment: В текущем случае с списком, вы вызываете insert и говорите что значений будет 8, но передаете 1.

Comment: @gil9red всё ещё хуже: как for-цикл так и `executemany()` являются лишними.

Answer (score 1):

Если `ar` содержит ровно столько элементов сколько колонок в таблице, то чтобы добавить одну строчку в таблицу `Goods`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3

c = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c.execute('create table goods (age, name)')
ar = [1, '2']
c.execute('insert into goods values (%s)' % ','.join('?'*len(ar)), ar)
print(*c.execute('select * from goods'))
# -> (1, '2')
```

Comment: а если в базе 8 полей, а у меня в массиве 5, а остальные 3 нужно сделать NULL

Comment: @Sasha: а это уже другой вопрос. Если не знаете как NULL вставить в sqlite на Питоне, то задайте отдельный вопрос. Если не знаете как `None` добавить к списку, чтобы его длина стала N (где `N==8` в вашем случае), то задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: вставил c.execute('insert into Goods values (%s)' % ','.join('?'*len(ar)), ar) , код запустился, но не вставил в базу

Comment: @Sasha: код работает как есть. Расширил пример до полного.